# Прозрачный текст на фоне

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

Подскажите как возможно сделать прозрачные буквы на зеленом фоне, чтобы был виден второй фон в буквах (зеленый фон должен в буквах отсутствовать, он только вокруг букв)

Пробовал с помощью,

```
text-transform: uppercase;
mix-blend-mode: multiply;
```

Но зеленый цвет обесцвечивается
[image: Пример]

Comment: попробуйте через text-shadow

Comment: @Arcadiy, я уже попробоавл - получается фигня))

Comment: Посмотрите [Пример на w3c](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_cutout_text.asp) и [пример на  css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/css-techniques-and-effects-for-knockout-text/). Есть еще на stackoverflow [обсуждение этой темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1170505/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0) точнее [перевод английской версии](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932946/transparent-text-cut-out-of-background)

Comment: в svg перегоните - уберёте заливку и оставите контур букв и получите свой эффект

Comment: Спасибо за подсказ, посмотрим что получится. а про svg не совсем понял, не часто с данным форматом сталкиваюсь

Comment: про svg смотри сам: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/xxXaevd

Comment: как видно свг работает отлично а вот подобное css свойство для шрифта не очень ... вам думать и выбирать что удобнее

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932946/transparent-text-cut-out-of-background - вариант на чистом css, и jq-вариант, но не кроссбраузерный.. Можно еще на php .png-картинку сделать. ))) Помимо svg можно на canvas намалевать.

Comment: @Zombotron обожаю людей которые сопротивляются силе свг ... без всяких серверных яп свг выигрывает ... хотя я люблю php

Comment: @Айболит еще более странно сопротивляться силе простого CSS https://caniuse.com/background-clip-text

Comment: @Айболит А, где я сопротивлялся? Просто предложил еще варианты. Например, я люблю поизвращаться с реализацией всяких приколов, типа исования на css2, аякс без js и т.п...

Answer (score 6):

Используя [canvas (XOR)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation), и [функцию переноса строк](https://thewebdev.info/2021/08/28/how-to-wrap-text-in-a-canvas-element-with-javascript/), вполне можно реализовать что-то похожее. Работает это быстро, и в принципе может быть использовано в адаптиве, придется лишь выбирать размеры канваса и шрифта.

```js
const wrapText = (ctx, text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight) => {
  const words = text.split(' ');
  let line = '';
  for (const [index, w] of words.entries()) {
    const testLine = line + w + ' ';
    const metrics = ctx.measureText(testLine);
    const testWidth = metrics.width;
    if (testWidth > maxWidth && index > 0) {
      ctx.fillText(line, x, y);
      line = w + ' ';
      y += lineHeight;
    } else {
      line = testLine;
    }
  }
  ctx.fillText(line, x, y);
}

const drawText = (text, fontSize, width, height, background) => {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.setAttribute('width', width)
  canvas.setAttribute('height', height)
  ctx.fillStyle = background;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'xor';
  ctx.font = `${fontSize}px Courier bold`;
  wrapText(ctx, text, 0, fontSize, width, fontSize * 1.2)
  document.body.appendChild(canvas)
}

drawText('#котики #cats #pets', 60, 500, 200, '#39B085D9')
```

```css
img {
    z-index: -1;
  }
  canvas {
    display: block-inline;
    margin-top: -5px;
    padding:0;
  }
```

```html
<img src="https://loremflickr.com/640/360" style="position: absolute;">
```

Comment: вроде бы(если я верно понял) то это как раз svg умеет : https://jsfiddle.net/njkr4tex/1/

Comment: @Айболит в таком случае можно оформить тоже как ответ

Comment: Никогда б не подумал, что это проблематично сделать будет

Comment: @GhostGames тоже думал будет проще, но хорошо что есть решения из которых можно выбирать

Answer (score 4):

Для прорезания верхнего фона по контурам букв, можно воспользоваться `mix-blend-mode:screen;`

```css
html {
background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJwH0.jpg) center/cover;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
min-height:100vh;
position:relative;
}
.text {
position:absolute;
background:#40FFF5;
mix-blend-mode:screen;
font-size:48px;
font-weight:900;
padding:0.2em;
width:10em;
left:0%;
top:15%;

}
```

```html
<div class="text">Flora truck - это крупнейший авиа экспедитор и один из самых крупных перевозчиков </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

### Решение SVG + CSS

Полная адаптивность, работает одинаково во всех современных браузерах.

Легко поддается переналадке ( все размеры  абсолютные и не зависят друг от друга)

```css
body,html{height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;}
body{
  background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYTL9.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  background-attachment:fixed;
}

.container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg viewbox="0 -35  400 240">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="240">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff"/>
       <text  font-size="14px" x="10" y="40" font-family="sans-serif" font-weight="700" >
         <tspan>Flora truck - это крупнейший</tspan>
          <tspan x="14" dy="20">авиа экспедитор и один из</tspan> 
          <tspan x="10" dy="20">самых крупных перевозчиков</tspan> </text>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect x="5" y="25" width="225" height="60" mask="url(#mask)" fill="#31C2BB" fill-opacity="0.8"/>    
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Текст к делу не относится

```css
.bg{
    background: #3acaca;
    max-width: 320px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #42242400;
    font-size: 25px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1.5px #585858;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
Разным ресурсам (стили, скрипты, шрифты и т. д.), браузеры обычно назначают разные приоритеты, чтобы в первую очередь загружать самые важные ресурсы. В данном случае браузер определяет приоритет по атрибуту as. Для браузера Chrome можете посмотреть полную таблицу приоритетов.
</div>
```

Comment: Такое то понятно, это раз и готово, но тут загвоздка, что надо фон прорезать первый

Comment: @GhostGames как понять `что надо фон прорезать первый` ? вы хотя бы покажите похожее

Comment: В описание написано, необходимо сделать буквы прозрачными , чтобы второй фон был виден, но 1 слой (зеленый) он должен быть вокруг букв. В буквах он должен отсутствовать

Comment: Если б все так просто было )), а так да твой вариант работает если 1 фон, то ок. Но тут нужно чтобы сами буквы были прозрачные и фон на котором они находят тоже прозрачным был.

Comment: А пример , вот https://codepen.io/rpsthecoder/pen/Zremwz, но опять же только с темными цветами ок работает

Comment: @GhostGames  я же показал два варианта ... и это не проблемно сделать

Comment: я по его вопросу, он спросил, я ответил)